# How does EF migrations choose a localdb version?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, localdb, entity-framework-migrations

My development machine has multiple versions of LocalDb. After running an initial EF migration the database was created in `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` (SQL Server 12.0.4213...). I expected it to land in `(localdb)\v11.0` (SQL Server 11.0.3000...).

The connection string in `app.config` is

```
<add name="HomeCinemaDan" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=HomeCinemaDan;Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What configuration line does EF migrations read to determine which db version to install to?

Background: I'm following [this tutorial](https://chsakell.com/2015/08/23/building-single-page-applications-using-web-api-and-angularjs-free-e-book/) and I've reached the end of the Data Repositories segment (I'm at the line that reads `update-database -verbose`). I've changed the database name to HomeCinemaDan.

Comment: And when you create the context, are you passing the correct connection string name?

Comment: Yes. The DBContext constructor is:  public HomeCinemaDanContext() : base("HomeCinemaDan")

Comment: And when you run `update-database` the default project in the package manager console is the project where migrations, context and connection string are defined?

Comment: Yes. In my case it's Default project: HomeCinemaDan.Data

Comment: What version(s) of SQL LocalDB do you have installed? In the 2012 version the default instance is called "v11.0" but in 2014 and later it is called "MSSQLLocalDB". If you only have the latter, it's possible that some backwards-compatibility-type code in the SQL LocalDB Instance API is switching the name "v11.0" meaning "the default instance" to the name appropriate for the latest version installed on the machine.

Comment: I have both v11.0 and MSSQLLocalDB.

Comment: My hunch would be that the P/Invoke under the hood is loading the later of the two versions, and then the "default instance" name as-was is being altered to the name naming convention. The C header file that ships with the SQL LocalDB Instance API behaves this way, and I've replicated this behaviour in my OSS library that wraps the API for C#. In SQL LocalDB 2012 the default instance name "v11.0" probably created confusion with the API version (11.0.3000), causing the name change to "SQSQLLocalDB" (and removing the need to update the name over time).

Comment: Here's an example of the name vs. version "complication": https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb/blob/master/src/SqlLocalDb/SqlLocalDbApi.cs#L103-L116

Comment: OK sounds like my confusion was justified. If you feel like submitting an answer I'll mark it as accepted.